# Arduino 8x8 led matrix letters

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, led

I have an Arduino 8x8 led attached to a shield on the Arduino. Now I want it to display some text. I've discovered how to make the correct byte for each letter. But I have no clue how to light it on my display. The tutorials I see on the internet are not really understandable. I would like to use a function where I can fill in the letter I want to use and how long it should be on the display. Like this: `displayLetter(byte letter[], int timeOnDisplay)`
Any advice is nice.

I don't the know model, it was included in my Elektor Arduino kit. It can be seen at link. Currently I have declared all my bytes like this

```
byte A[] = {     
    B00000000,
    B00111100,
    B01100110,
    B01100110,
    B01111110,
    B01100110,
    B01100110,
    B01100110};
```

as well as

```
void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    for (byte i = 2; i <= 13; i++) 
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(A0, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(A1, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(A2, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(A3, OUTPUT); 
}
```

Which I got from an online tutorial.

I use an Arduino Uno and my 8x8 led is connected via a shield.

Greetings

Comment: You didn't provide any link nor connection diagram for you module to Arduino nor Arduino board type.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the input type of the matrix, I'm going to assume it's controlled via column and row inputs and not SPI based on the sample code you provided.

Below is a sample I put together real quick to demonstrate looping through the alphabet and displaying a letter for a specified amount of time.  This code does work, you must connect the 8x8 led matrix inputs to the corresponding pin callouts for the rows and columns in the code provided (or change the code pins to match your connection configuration).

These work by multiplexing which means the signals are shared between leds, each row input pin connects to 8 leds and each column is also connected to 8 leds.  To turn on a particular led, it needs the correct signal from both the row pin it's connected to and also the column pin it's connected it.  So for example, to turn on the led at the bottom right corner, a signal needs to be sent to the last row pin and also the last column pin; if you wanted to turn on all the leds in the last column, a signal needs to be sent to all row pins and just the last column pin.

To display shapes/letters requires a little more processing power as you cannot just turn on a few columns and rows and leave them on.  To accomplish this, you need to loop through each row and each column, turning on the needed leds for a brief period of time and then turn them off again; doing this fast enough makes it appear as if all of the leds are on at the same time.

[image]

```
    /*
 Name:      Arduino8x8MatrixStackOverflow.ino
 Created:   3/10/2019 5:21:02 PM
 Author:    jjman
*/
//Connect these pins to the corresponding row input of the 8x8 matrix.
const unsigned char RowPins[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
//Connect these pins to the corresponding column input of the 8x8 matrix.
const unsigned char ColumnPins[] = {10,11,12,13,A0,A1,A2,A3};

unsigned char A[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B01100110,B01100110,B01111110,B01100110,B01100110,B01100110};
unsigned char B[] = {B01111000,B01001000,B01001000,B01110000,B01001000,B01000100,B01000100,B01111100};
unsigned char C[] = {B00000000,B00011110,B00100000,B01000000,B01000000,B01000000,B00100000,B00011110};
unsigned char D[] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100010,B00100010,B00100100,B00111000,B00000000};
unsigned char E[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111000,B00100000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000};
unsigned char F[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00000000};
unsigned char G[] = {B00000000,B00111110,B00100000,B00100000,B00101110,B00100010,B00111110,B00000000};
unsigned char H[] = {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000};
unsigned char I[] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00111000,B00000000};
unsigned char J[] = {B00000000,B00011100,B00001000,B00001000,B00001000,B00101000,B00111000,B00000000};
unsigned char K[] = {B00000000,B00100100,B00101000,B00110000,B00101000,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000};
unsigned char L[] = {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000};
unsigned char M[] = {B00000000,B00000000,B01000100,B10101010,B10010010,B10000010,B10000010,B00000000};
unsigned char N[] = {B00000000,B00100010,B00110010,B00101010,B00100110,B00100010,B00000000,B00000000};
unsigned char O[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B00111100,B00000000};
unsigned char P[] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111000,B00100000,B00100000,B00000000};
unsigned char Q[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B01000110,B00111110,B00000001};
unsigned char R[] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000};
unsigned char S[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111100,B00000100,B00000100,B00111100,B00000000};
unsigned char T[] = {B00000000,B01111100,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00000000};
unsigned char U[] = {B00000000,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B00100100,B00011000,B00000000};
unsigned char V[] = {B00000000,B00100010,B00100010,B00100010,B00010100,B00010100,B00001000,B00000000};
unsigned char W[] = {B00000000,B10000010,B10010010,B01010100,B01010100,B00101000,B00000000,B00000000};
unsigned char X[] = {B00000000,B01000010,B00100100,B00011000,B00011000,B00100100,B01000010,B00000000};
unsigned char Y[] = {B00000000,B01000100,B00101000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00000000};
unsigned char Z[] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00000100,B00001000,B00010000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000};

unsigned char *Alphabet[] = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z};
unsigned char AlphabetCharactersLower[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};


unsigned char* DisplayBuffer = nullptr;

unsigned char DisplayIndex = 0;
unsigned long DisplayLetterBeginMilliseconds = 0;
unsigned long DisplayLetterEndMilliseconds = 0;
bool DisplayActive = false;

void setup()
{
    // Open serial port
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Sets up all of the row pins to be used as outputs.
    for(unsigned char i = 0; i < sizeof(RowPins); i++)
    {
        pinMode(RowPins[i], OUTPUT);
    }
    //Sets up all of the column pins to be used as outputs.
    for(unsigned char i = 0; i < sizeof(ColumnPins); i++)
    {
        pinMode(ColumnPins[i], OUTPUT);
    }
}


//Resets the values used to time the duration of display.
void SetDisplayTiming(const unsigned displayMilliseconds)
{
    DisplayLetterBeginMilliseconds = millis();
    DisplayLetterEndMilliseconds = DisplayLetterBeginMilliseconds + displayMilliseconds;
    DisplayActive = true;
}

void UpdateDisplay()
{
    //Loop through rows.
    for(unsigned char i = 0; i < sizeof(RowPins); i++)
    {
        //Loop through columns.
        for(unsigned char j = 0; j < sizeof(ColumnPins); j++)
        {
            //Turn column on for the corresponding bit.
            digitalWrite(ColumnPins[j], ~DisplayBuffer[i] >> j & 1);
        }
        //Turn on row to activate led.
        digitalWrite(RowPins[i], 1);

        //Uncomment the delay to increase brightness.  With 8 rows, any delay greater than 2 ms will cause flickering.  This is due to the refresh rate dropping below 60hz.
        //delayMicroseconds(2000);

        //Turn row back off.
        digitalWrite(RowPins[i], 0);
    }
}


//Updates the DisplayBuffer to the corresponding letter.  Letter can be either uppercase, 'A', or lowercase 'a'.
void SetDisplayLetter(char letter)
{
    //If letter supplied is an uppercase letter, subtract 65 to zero the letter so it can be used as an index. (The 'A' character has an integer value of 65)
    if(letter > 64 && letter < 91) letter -= 65;
    //If letter supplied is a lowercase letter, subtract 97 to zero the letter so it can be used as an index.  (The 'a' character has an integer value of 97)
    else if(letter > 96 && letter < 123) letter -= 97;
    //Letter supplied is not a lowercase or uppercase letter, print error to serial.
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error - Function: 'DisplayLetter' Cause: Specified Letter character is not an alphabet character");
        return;
    }
    DisplayBuffer = Alphabet[letter];
}
void SetDisplayLetter(const char letter, const unsigned displayMilliseconds)
{
    SetDisplayLetter(letter);
    SetDisplayTiming(displayMilliseconds);
}

//If it's time to display the next letter, do so.
void TryToDisplayNextLetter()
{
    //Letter is currently displayed, now we can check to see if enough time has elapsed for us to turn it off.
    if(DisplayActive)
    {
        //If enough time has elapsed, turn off display to allow display of the next letter.
        if(millis() > DisplayLetterEndMilliseconds)
        {
            DisplayActive = false;
        }
        return;
    }
    SetDisplayLetter(AlphabetCharactersLower[DisplayIndex],200);
    //Counts up the index for the next letter.
    DisplayIndex++;
    //Reset the index to zero if we just displayed the last letter in the alphabet.
    if(DisplayIndex == 26) DisplayIndex = 0;
}

//This example does not use delays and is non-blocking.
void loop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        TryToDisplayNextLetter();
        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    //Add other code as necessary.
}
```